# What do you say when you talk over phone but you can't quite hear what other person says?

Tags: telephone

I bought my first phone in my life and I now sometimes get calls from friends and co workers. Sometimes the signal of phone doesn't work well and I can't hear them.

What do I say when there is silence or noises?

So far I have thought of the following:

```
* Sorry I didn't hear you, can you repeat that?
* What was that, I didn't hear you?
* Oh what was that, I didn't hear you?
* I didn't hear you, can you repeat that?
* Can you repeat that?
* Sorry I didn't hear you?
* Sorry?
```

What else can I say?

Comment: I'd say the same things you've got listed there.

Comment: 'Could you speak up, please'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to inform the other person that you're having difficulty understanding them because the signal is weak, you could say:

TO FRIENDS/INFORMAL:

Sorry, I didn't catch that. You're fading out.

FORMAL

I'm sorry, but I didn't hear what you said just then. We have a bad connection.

or

I'm sorry, but we have a bad connection and I'm unable to hear you clearly.

Answer (score 1):

All of your suggestions are good.

You can also start off by saying one of:

> Sorry. I can't hear you.
>
> Sorry. I didn't catch that.

Then follow it up with any of:

> It's a bad line.
>
> The line is bad.
>
> You're breaking up.
>
> You're distorting.
>
> You're cutting out.

There are a lot of other ways of saying the same thing.